# last function in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm using the last() function to try to get the last entry in my xml as so:

```
//Name[last()]
```

however, it is returning the list to me rather than just the last name in the document... any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common gotcha due to what "//" stands for. Many people assume it stands for the descendant axis, but it actually stands for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

`//Name[last()]` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/Name[last()]`, which makes more obvious the fact that this expression actually contains two steps:

1. `/descendant-or-self::node()`, which selects the context node and all its descendants, and
2. `Name[last()]`, which selects the last `<Name>` child of the context node.

Step #2 is evaluated once for each node returned by step 1. If step 1 returns 10 nodes, than step 2 (and thus the entire expression) can return up to 10 nodes as well.

If you instead encapsulate the expression with parentheses, you can use an "expression filter" rather than a "step filter": `(//Name)[last()]`

This ensures that the entire expression will return no more than 1 `<Name>` element, specifically, the last one in document order among all the  elements returned by the expression to its left.

For more details and nuances, check out this email thread: http://markmail.org/thread/otd3iz5lag72emq4#query:+page:1+mid:qdsrmjrbbdvve3c3+state:results

And this article: http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xpath-punctuation-part-5

Comment: thank you! makes a lot of sense now - these things aren't always apparent when you're learning.

Answer (score 2):

`//Name[last()]` selects all `Name` elements that are the last child of its parent.

Try `(//Name)[last()]` instead.